# Maximum Eigenvalue Algorithm with Multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

The problem is as follows...

"A real-symmetric matrix A has an eigenvalue of 1 of multiplicity 8, while the rest of the eigenvalues are all ≤0.1 in absolute value. Describe an algorithm for finding an orthonormal basis of the 8-dimensional eigenspace corresponding to the domininant eigenvalue."

My thought is iterating using the block power method (or subspace iteration) with X being the n by n identity matrix, and then just taking the first 8 columns. Is that a correct intuition?

Comment: " block power method (or subspace iteration) with X being the n by n identity matrix"; you speak about what ? Here, you know the dominant eigenvalue!

Comment: @loupblanc  
Okay. Is there a simpler way I’m missing?

Comment: If $n$ is not large, then i) find a basis $B$ of $\ker(A-I)$; ii) apply to $B$ the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization . If $n$ is large, then we can do better...